# Creating Custom Table Cell Renderers (buttons and text boxes)

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer, tablecelleditor

I was wondering how i can make a customized table in java??? I want it to have 4 text boxes and then a button. If someone can tell me how to do this for my table, I'd be ever so grateful.

Comment: `TableModels` are used for storing data that can be displayed in a table. `TableCellRenderers` and `TableCellEditors` are used for displaying the table data in a custom way, such as writing it out as a `String`, or displaying `JCheckBoxes` or `JButtons`. Don't get these mixed up!

Answer (score 4):

basically, what you want to do is not a table model but customize cell editors and renderers. I hope this document can clarify your doubts, [Official JTables tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Good Luck!